# tikzpicture arrow from one plot to another

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, arrows

I'm new to tikz and I want to do some kind like in the figure below :

[[image: multiple curves plot to matrix[1]]

I trie to do something but i don't kown how to put to matrix in the left of the plot and to draw an arrow betewwen them ?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black},
space/.style={minimum height=1.5em,matrix of nodes,row sep=-
\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 1/.style=
{font=\ttfamily}},text depth=0.5ex,text height=2ex,nodes in empty cells]

\matrix (matrice) [
space, 
column 2/.style={minimum width=5em,nodes={cell,minimum width=3.5em}},
column 3/.style={nodes={cell,minimum width=4em}},
 column 4/.style={nodes={cell,minimum width=4em}}]
 {
 $t_1$   &6  & 6  & 7    \\ 
 $t_2$   &3  & 3.5  & 8    \\   
 $t_3$   &4  & 9  & 9    \\ 
 $t_4$   &7  & 9  & 0    \\ };

 \begin{axis}[left= of matrice,
 xlabel=time,
 ylabel=$f(\textrm{temps})$,
 xtick distance=1,
 legend pos=north west
 ,grid=major]
 \addplot  [color=green] table {
 Date GDP  
 1 6
 2 3
 3 4
 4 7
 };
  \addplot [color=blue] table {
 Date X
 1 5
 2 4
 3 5
 4 4
 };
 \addplot [color=red]table {
Date X
1 5.2
2 4.2
3 5.1
4 4.05
 };
\addplot [color=purple]table {
Date X
 1 3.2
 2 4.2
 3 5.19
 4 4.05
 };
 \legend{$sensor 1$, $sensor 2$, $sensor2$}
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: what i had done with tikz]

Response @Zarko, your reply helps me but i still have problem with the (time and value) axis as you can see in the figure below (why the number are above the horizontal line ?!) :

[image]

and the new code is (in fact I can't use the standalone class sine i use the book class):

```
       \begin{tikzpicture} 
       \begin{axis}[name=p, legend pos=north west, grid =major, symbolic x            coords={$t_1$,$t_2$,$t_3$,$t_4$,$t_5$,$t_6$,$t_7$,$t_8$,$t_n$}] 
         \addplot+[smooth] coordinates { 
                   ($t_1$,42) 
                   ($t_2$,50) 
                   ($t_3$,80) 
                   ($t_4$,60) 
                   ($t_5$,62) 
                   ($t_n$,90)}; 

         \addplot+[smooth,color=red] coordinates { 
                   ($t_1$,45) 
                   ($t_2$,30) 
                   ($t_3$,70) 
                   ($t_4$,90) 
                   ($t_5$,32) 
                   ($t_n$,50)}; 
                     \addplot+[smooth,color=green] coordinates { 
                   ($t_1$,35) 
                   ($t_2$,20) 
                   ($t_3$,80) 
                   ($t_4$,60) 
                   ($t_5$,22) 
                   ($t_n$,40)};
                   \legend{\emph{capteur} 1, \emph{capteur} 2,\emph{capteur} 3}
           \end{axis} 
       \matrix (matrice) [matrix of math nodes,
                           nodes={draw, font=\ttfamily,
                                  minimum width=4em, text depth=0.5ex, text height=2ex},
                           column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                           right=of p]    {
       & {\color{red}$c_1$} & {\color{blue}$c_2$} &{\color{green}$c_3$}                 \\  
       $t_1$&   6  &    6   &   7   \\
       $t_2$ &   3  &   3   &   8   \\
       $t_3$ &   4  &   9   &   9   \\
                  $t_4$ &   7  &   9   &   0   \\
       $t_5$ &  .  &    .  &    . \\
       $.$ &  .  &    .  &    .  \\
       $.$ &   .  &    .  &    .  \\
       $.$ &   .  &    .  &    .  \\
       $t_n$ &   7  &   9   &   0   \\
       };
       \draw[ultra thick,-Straight Barb, shorten <=1mm, shorten            >=1mm,color=black]
           (p) -- (matrice);    
       \end{tikzpicture}
```

while the preambule is

```
  ` \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}%,12pt draft twoside
     \def\version{0.5}
     % \def\padding{\input{padding.txt}}
\def\x{\ensuremath{\times}}
\def\bul{\ensuremath{\bullet}}
\def\cir{\ensuremath{\circ}}
%\def\release{v.\version, r.\svnrev}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{aeguill}%défaut [lm]
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.02} 
\newcommand{\mc}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand{\mr}[3]{\multirow{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand{\note}[1]         {\marginpar[\raggedleft\footnotesize\itshape#1\par{\raggedright\footnotesiz\itshape#1\par}}

        \newcommand{\removenotes}{\renewcommand{\note}[1]{}}
         \newcommand{\vertc}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{#1}}}
         \newcommand{\vertcr}[1]{\rotatebox{-90}{\textbf{#1}}}
         \newcommand{\vertcn}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}
         \usepackage{url}
         \usepackage{xspace}
         \usepackage[active]{srcltx}
         \usepackage{moreverb}
         %\usepackage{svn-multi}
        % \svnid{$Id: MainThese.tex 401 2008-05-15 16:59:00Z rthion $}
        \usepackage{datetime}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{amsthm}
        \usepackage{amssymb}
        \DeclareMathOperator{\precprec}{ \prec\!\prec}
        \DeclareMathOperator{\succsucc}{ \succ\!\succ}
        \theoremstyle{plain}
        \newtheorem{thm}{Théorème}%[thm]
        \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}%[thm]
        \newtheorem{defni}{Définition}
         \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemme}
        \usepackage[french,vlined,linesnumbered,algoruled,lined,boxed]{algorithm2e}     
         \overfullrule=5pt
         \usepackage[a4paper, hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}
         \geometry{marginparwidth=3cm}
         \addtolength{\headheight}{2.3pt}
         \parskip=5pt
         \usepackage{graphicx}
         \usepackage{epsfig}
        \usepackage{subfigure}
         \usepackage{wrapfig}
        \usepackage{tabularx,lscape,longtable,booktabs}
        \usepackage{slashbox}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \renewcommand{\multirowsetup}{\centering}
         \usepackage{rotating}
        \tolerance = 400
        \hyphenpenalty=50
        \hbadness = 1500
        \hfuzz 0pt
        \emergencystretch 1em %\emergencystretch 1.5em
        \clubpenalty=9999
        \widowpenalty=9999
     %  \widowpenalty=10000
        \vfuzz \hfuzz
        \raggedbottom




        \usepackage{lettrine}

        \usepackage[usenames]{color}
        \usepackage[table]{xcolor}


         \definecolor{gris10}{rgb}{0.75,0.75,0.75}
        \definecolor{gris60}{rgb}{0.60,0.60,0.60}
        \definecolor{gris80}{rgb}{0.40,0.40,0.40}               


        \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
        \usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
        \usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes


        %\usepackage{algorithm}
         \usepackage{algorithmic} 


         \usepackage[helvetica]{quotchap}
         \makeatletter\def\@seccntformat#1{\protect\makebox[0pt][r]{\csname          the#1\endcsname\hspace{12pt}}}\makeatother

        \usepackage{titlesec}   
        \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
        \titlespacing*{\paragraph} {0pt}{1ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0pt}
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \pagestyle{fancyplain}
         \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Chapitre \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
                \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{Section \thesection.\ #1}}
        \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}] {\fancyplain{}         {\bfseries\rightmark}}          
        \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}] {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}

         \cfoot{}

         \let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
        \newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
        \clearpage
        {\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}%
        }
        \let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage 

        %\usepackage[a4paper,ps2pdf,linktocpage,bookmarksnumbered,pagebackref]{hyperref}
         \usepackage[linktocpage,bookmarksnumbered,pagebackref]{hyperref}

         \usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}


         \usepackage[section,notlof,notlot,notbib]{tocbibind}
         \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

        \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
            \usepackage{float}



         \floatstyle{ruled}

         \newfloat{floexample}{thpb}{loe}[chapter]
         \floatname{floexample}{Exemple}

     %\newcommand{\listdefinitionsname}{Liste des définitions}
     %\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Liste des tables}


         \newlistof[chapter]{definitions}{def}{\listdefinitionsname}
         \setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2em}  
         \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}    %réduit l'espacement
         \setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}   %réduit l'espacement
         \setlength{\cftdefinitionsindent}{1.5em}
        \setlength{\cftdefinitionsnumwidth}{2.3em}
        \usepackage[french,nohints]{minitoc}%
        \mtcsettitle{minitoc}{Plan du chapitre}
        \mtcsetfeature{minitoc}{after}{\clearpage}
        \mtcsetdepth{minitoc}{2}
        \newenvironment{defn}[1]
        %encapsulation de l'env théorème defni
        {   
             \begin{defni}[#1]
            {
                \refstepcounter{definitions}
            }
            {
                \addcontentsline{def}{definitions}                  {\protect\numberline{\thedefinitions}{#1}}
            }  
        }
        {
            \end{defni}     
        }   

        \newenvironment{exemple}[1]
        %def de l'environnement "exemple" qui encadre la description d'un exemple et numérote par chapitre
{           \begin{floexample}
            \begin{center}
            \begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
            \caption{\sffamily #1} \sffamily \small \medskip    
        }%à l'ouverture \begin
        {   \end{minipage}
            \end{center}    
            \end{floexample}
        }%à la fermeture \end

     \newenvironment{myQuote}
        {   \begin{quote} %         \hspace{-5pt}
            \itshape        
        }%à l'ouverture \begin
        {
            \end{quote}%\par                
        }%à la fermeture \end


     \newenvironment{resume}
        {   %\textsc{Résumé}
     %      \itshape \small
            \vfill \itshape \small %\sffamily
            $\vartriangleright$}
        {   $\vartriangleleft$ \par \vfill
            \clearpage
                    \minitoc}
     %------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


     % Infos spécifiques aux pdfs
     %----------------------------------------------------------------------         --------------
            \hypersetup{
            pdfauthor   = {},%
            pdftitle    = {},%
            pdfsubject  = {},%
            pdfkeywords = {},%
    }   




         \usepackage{pgfplots} 
         \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
         \usepackage{tikz}
         \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
         \usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit}
         \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
         \usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
         \usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit,tikzmark}
         \usepackage{verbatim}
         \usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
         \usepackage{tabularx}
          \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

         % définition des styles
         \tikzstyle{lien}=[->,>=stealth]
         \tikzset{individu/.style={#1!100},individu/.default={black}}





         \tikzset{   
                every picture/.style={remember picture,baseline},
                every node/.style={anchor=base,align=center,outer sep=1.5pt},
                          every path/.style={thick},
               }

         \newcommand\marktopleft[1]{%
           \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
                 \node (marker-#1-a) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
         }
         \newcommand\markbottomright[1]{%
            \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
                \node (marker-#1-b) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
            \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=5pt]
               \node[draw=red,rounded corners,fit=(marker-#1-a) (marker-#1-b)] {};%
         }




         \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
         \tikzset{main node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,draw,minimum             size=1cm,inner sep=0pt},
                     }



         \let\clipbox\relax
         \usepackage{adjustbox}
         \usepackage{rotating}


         \DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}
         \DeclareMathOperator*{\argminA}{arg\,min} 
         \DeclareMathOperator*{\argminB}{argmin} 
         \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
         %\usepackage{algpseudocode}
         \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

         \newcommand{\listtheoremname}{Liste des Théorèmes}

         \newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}          {1}\tag{\theequation}}
         \usepackage{pifont}
         \newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
         \newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
         %\newtheorem{lemma}{lemme} 
         %\usepackage{ams}
         \def\T{\rm T}
         \def\M{\rm M}
         \def\R{\rm R}
         \def\RR{\mathbb R}
         \def\D{\rm D}
         \def\L{\rm L}
         \def\I{\rm I}
         \def\W{\rm W}
         \usepackage{bm}
         \usepackage{bibentry}
         \usepackage{epstopdf}
         \usepackage{pdfpages}






         \providecommand{\keys}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords---}} #1}


         \usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
         \usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
         \usepackage{pgfplots}
         \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
         \pgfplotsset{xticklabel={\tick},scaled x ticks=false}
         \pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
         \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix, positioning}
```

`

Comment: It's probably easier to keep the two tikz pictures separate and then use a simple display math environment for the arrow, something like: `\[ (first pic) \longrightarrow (second pic) \]`

Comment: Also welcome to TeX.SE!  Can you please post a **compilable** example including the minimum preamble, instead of posting a snippet?

Comment: Thank you @Thruston :)  i edit my question to reply  to Zarko

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit (1)**:

meanwhile i figured out that we can give a name to plots an draw all images as one picture:

**edit (2)**:

- considered is table as is shown in your edited answer
- please use code in `pgfplots` as well in `matrix` as they are in my answer. your modifying introduce errors in it

[image]

in a case of the three images:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=22mm]
\begin{axis}[
name=p,
    xlabel = time,
    ylabel =$ f(\textrm{temps})$,
    xtick distance=1,
    grid=major]
\addplot table {Date GDP
                 1 6
                 2 3
                 3 4
                 4 7
                 };
\addplot table {Date X
                 1 5
                 2 4
                 3 5
                 4 4
                 };
\addplot table {Date X
                1 5.2
                2 4.2
                3 5.1
                4 4.05
                 };
\addplot table {Date X
                 1 3.2
                 2 4.2
                 3 5.19
                 4 4.05
                 };
\legend{\emph{sensor} 1, \emph{sensor} 2, \emph{sensor} 3,\emph{sensor} 4}
\end{axis}
\matrix (matrice)  [matrix of math nodes,
                    nodes={draw, font=\ttfamily,
                           minimum width=3em, text depth=0.4ex, text height=1.75ex},
                    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                    right=of p]    {
t_1 &   6  &    6   &   7   \\
t_2 &   3  &    3.5 &   8   \\
t_3 &   4  &    9   &   9   \\
t_4 &   7  &    9   &   0   \\
};
\draw[ultra thick,-Straight Barb, shorten <=2mm, shorten >=2mm]
    (p) -- (matrice);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your response,it helps me, but i still have  a problem with the axis as you cas see in the below picture

Comment: @FiesAtoS,  (i) you should not modified code (you enter errors in it) (ii) please always provide complete small document (in preamble maybe you have settings which somehow override proposed solution (iii) in answer is matrix as you show in original question. please,  edit your question and make it clear and consider my comments.

Comment: Zarko, I edited my question and i put the premabule. The  probleme is that if i use only your tex document with standlone package it works fine, however i does not work inside my whole docuement with the preambul i putted in the question.

Comment: @FiesAtoS, sorry, but your preamble, is frankly said, terrible. please first remove all duplicates. check again, if you really need all `pgfplotsset` in (presumably they are guilty for your troubles, now i haven't time to check this). i suggest to remove them temporally, that you see, if then you obtain the same result as with my answer.